# Is it true that $q^6-1$ and $q^2-1$ always have at least one different prime divisor, where $q$ is a prime power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $q$ be a prime power. Is it true that $q^6-1$ and $q^2-1$ always have at least one prime different divisor? It is sufficient to prove $q^2-1$ has one prime divisor different from those of $q^4+q^2+1$, since $q^6-1=(q^2-1)(q^4+q^2+1)$. It seems true intuitively... But how can I prove it? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you leave out *different* in the title?  Do you know $q^3-1=(q-1)(q^2+q+1)$?

Comment: $q^6-1=(q^2-1)(q^4+q^2+1)$. One divides the other.

Comment: $q^4+q^2+1=(q^2+q+1)(q^2-q+1)$. If $p|(q\pm1)$ then $=3\ne0\pmod{p}$.

Comment: This should be helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem

Comment: @Peter Bravo! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two integers fail to have at least one prime different divisor each iff they have the same prime divisors.

We have $q^6-1=(q^2-1)(q^4+q^2+1)$. Moreover,
$
q^4+q^2+1=(q^2-1)(q^2+2)+3
$.
Therefore, $d=\gcd(q^2-1,q^4+q^2+1)=1$ or $3$.

If $d=1$, we're done.

If $d=3$, then the only way that $q^2-1$ and $q^4+q^2+1$ have the same prime divisors is that both are powers of $3$. Since $q^2-1 < q^4+q^2+1$, we must have $q^2-1=d=3$ and so $q=2$. But then $q^4+q^2+1=21$ is not a power of $3$.

Comment: Just because it took me a moment: $q^2-1$ must be $3$ because of the factorization $(q-1)(q+1)$; it's impossible for both $q-1$ and $q+1$ to be powers of 3 unless one of them is trivial.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, that's not my argument. $q^2-1$ must be $3$ because it's the smaller number and they're both powers of $3$, and their gcd is $3$.

Comment: Oh! That also makes perfect sense. I'd missed the point that the GCD was 3 exactly and that implies that one of them has to be 3. Mea culpa!